# What is the coefficient of ${x}^{101}{y}^{99}$ in the expression of $(2x-3y)^{200}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

I know that I have to use the binomial theorem. So, in following the formula of ${(1+x)}^{n} = {n \choose 0}+{n \choose 1}{x}+{n \choose 2}{x}^{2}...+{n \choose k}{x}^{k}+...+{n \choose n}{x}^{n}$, I came up with ${200 \choose 99}$, but I am certain that is not all the way correct, if at all.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Use the formula for $(a+b)^n$, not for $(1 + x)^n$.

Comment: 3904754518488540723864732575678578300263889231939218316050091512431332
1550428925707249194557139838908687841360366159334751041421836288000

Comment: You have to multiply $2^{101}\cdot (-3)^{99}$ with nCr$(200,99)$ to get the right coefficient.

Comment: Now, why do we multiply that number with nCr(200, 99)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binomial theorem states that
\begin{equation}
(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}.
\end{equation}
Let $a=2x, b=-3y, n=200,$ and $k=101$.